# Unable to update Isactive flag status in multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have model class like

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSKU> ProductSKUs { get; set; 
 }

public class ProductSKUResponse
{
    public int Skuid { get; set; }
    public String Sku { get; set; }
    public decimal MRP { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update `isactive` status in multiple tables but I don't find a 
solution so kindly requesting you please let me know the logic.

```
public async Task<ReturnBoolean> DeleteProductById(int Id, bool status)
{
    ReturnBoolean response = new ReturnBoolean();
    Contracts.Entities.Product product = await _productRepository.GetByIdAsync(Id);

    if (product == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to delete selected product, product does not exist");
    }

    product.IsActive = status;
    product.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    product.ProductSKUs = await productSkuRepository.GetProductSkus(Id);

    // from this onwards I didn't understand how to assign status value to in product.ProductSKUs.isactive.

    await _productRepository.UpdateAsync(product, true);
    response.BooleanValue = true;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: you can accept the helpful answer to mark the problem as fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try simple foreach

```
foreach(ProductSKU productSKU in product.ProductSKUs.ToList())
{
   productSKU.IsActive = status;
}
```

But it also depends on how this method is implemented `_productRepository.UpdateAsync(product, true)`

Comment: hi Roman after adding above logic its showing error like "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execut"

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid statements like:

```
product.ProductSKUs = await productSkuRepository.GetProductSkus(Id);
```

Either eager load them with the Product, or just update them separately. The trouble with generic repositories or repository-per-entity is that you can't easily leverage things like eager loading or the full power of Linq.

```
using (var context = new ProductContext())
{
   var product = context.Products.Include(x => x.ProductSKUs).Single(x => x.Id = ID);
   product.IsActive = status;
   foreach( var productSKU in product.ProductSKUs)
       productSKU.IsActive = status;
}
```

or using the repositories:

```
var productSKUs = await productSkuRepository.GetProductSkus(Id);
foreach( var productSKU in product.ProductSKUs)
    productSKU.IsActive = status;
```

Assigning the collection to product is probably Ok, but I'd be wary of assigning anything not related to the action in question because `SaveChanges` will look for all modifications and attempt to save them. Setting a collection after an entity is loaded is something that sends off warning signs whenever I see it. :)